# Get environment specific server app URL in grails service

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to get the server URL in Groovy, if I deploy in my local environment I want it to link to `localhost:8080` but on the test and live environment it should be different. Is there any way to do this in my Groovy service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Config.groovy

```
environments {
    development {
         grails.config.serverAppURL = YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_MODE_APP_URL 
    }
    production {
         grails.config.serverAppURL = YOUR_PRODUCTION_MODE_APP_URL
    }
    test {
         grails.config.serverAppURL = YOUR_TEST_MODE_APP_URL
    }
}
```

Access this url in your service

```
Class MyService {
   def grailsApplication // inject this service

   def testMethod(){
    def appUrl = grailsApplication.config.serverAppURL // getting url here
    println appUrl
   }

}
```

Comment: Can this be simple achieves in plain Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of your grails application

```
environments {
    development {
         grails.server.url = "localhost:8080"
    }
    production {
         grails.server.url = "http://example.com"
    }
    test {
         grails.server.url = "http://production.com"
    }
}
```

You can get your server URL using Holders like this.

```
class something {

    String getAppURL() {
      String serverURL = Holders.flatConfig.get("grails.server.url")
      return serverURL
    }
}
```